# How i can upload images to another folder?

Tags: uploads, media-settings

If I go in `Dashboard -> Settings -> Media` I don't see field where I can change upload folder. Is it possible now?
For example my website is `myblog.tld`, by default all media content uploads into `wp-content/uploads/year/month`. I want uploads all media to `sub.myblog.tld/year/month`

Thanks for advance.

PS WP 3.5, Sorry for my english.

Comment: What is sub.myblog.tld? is it another server, another directory on your server-root?

Comment: Oh, I don't understand your questions.. Sorry. I use as subdomain `subdomain.myblog.tld`, not `myblog.tld/subdomain/`. Similar `google.com` and subdomain is `plus.google.com`.

Comment: Is the subdomain sub.myblog.tld on the same server as myblog.tld ?

Comment: Yes, on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress we can change the default location of the wp-content folder by defining a couple constants in wp-config.php [about it here on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content)

So if the structure on the server looks like this:

```
/root/
 1. myblog.tld - its own directory
 2. sub.myblog.tld - its own directory
```

You can use this in your wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sub.myblog.tld' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://sub.myblog.tld');
```

It will change the upload dir to the one above the current root (myblog.tld to sub.myblog.tld). And the content-url will be sub.myblog.tld

Comment: Oh, yeah, how I could forget about wp-config.php? Thank you very much!